# How to destroy a particular resource before deleting other resources in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am creating a VPN using a **script** in Terraform as no provider function is available. This VPN also has some other attached resources like security groups.

So when I run `terraform destroy` it starts deleting the VPN but in parallel, it also starts deleting the security group. The security group deletion fails because those groups are "still" associated with the VPN which is in the process of deletion.

When I run `terraform destroy -parallelism=1` it works fine, but due to some limitations, I cannot use this in prod.

Is there a way I can enforce VPN to be deleted first before any other resource deletion starts?

**EDIT:**

See the security group and VPN Code:

```
resource "<cloud_provider>_security_group" "sg" {
  name           = format("%s-%s", local.name, "sg")
  vpc            = var.vpc_id
  resource_group = var.resource_group_id
}

resource "null_resource" "make_vpn" {

  triggers = {
    vpn_name     = var.vpn_name
    local_script = local.scripts_location
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "${local.scripts_location}/login.sh"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    environment = {
      API_KEY = var.api_key
    }
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = local_file.make_vpn.filename
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when       = "destroy"
    command    = <<EOT
      ${self.triggers.local_script}/delete_vpn_server.sh ${self.triggers.vpn_name}
    EOT
    on_failure = continue
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `-target` option for that.

Comment: But I want to delete every resource, just want to start with one particular

Comment: If that is the case, can you add the code to the question?

Comment: You could use the explicit dependency, by specifying `depends_on` in the VPN part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't affect the create/update/destroy order of terraform due to its internal workings and how it tracks dependencies, you can invert it but it's sometimes of little use. You'll find that pretty quick in any old google.

The suggestions here around `-target` aren't far off and are definitely a viable option. I don't know what your limitations were, if it was minimal downtime, a quickly reusable process or the lack of ability to add flags but that's what maintenance windows are for. There's a few ways I handle this depending on the situation, I'll give two examples.

In a situation where the depdency graph is actually correct, i.e. you have an implict or explicit depdency between 2 resources but the actions you're taking on 1 resource, say changing a property that causes a replacement, doesn't change a property in the second resource that causes a replacement. So one resource wants to replace and the other wants to update. You're at the mercy of the api at that point it's not terraforms job to fix that. Thus the link isn't actually broken at the api layer. So you're defining their lifecylce together and you should create and destroy them together. There's a few ways to do that.

`terraform apply -replace resource.a -replace resource.b`

This is the same if they're in a module i.e. `-replace module.a.resource.a`

Unfortunately there's no way to replace modules entirely together which would be cool

`terraform apply -replace=module.a`

This also raises questions about how you write terraform, what you group into modules and how you see infrastructure dependencies and their lifecylce.

Failing all of this, you could just comment them out and rerun an apply and tf will do the rest, this works pretty well for modules.